# Content security policy with grape-swagger-rails

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, ruby-grape

I am trying to get my site work with grape-swagger-rails, on the initialiser I have the following.

```
GrapeSwaggerRails.options.tap do |options|
  options.url      = '/api/swagger_doc.json'
  options.app_name = 'MyApp'
  options.api_auth = 'bearer'
  options.api_key_name = 'Authorization'
  options.api_key_type = 'header'
  options.doc_expansion = 'list'
end

GrapeSwaggerRails.options.before_action do
  GrapeSwaggerRails.options.app_url = request.protocol + request.host_with_port
end
```

Im my `routes.rb` I have `mount GrapeSwaggerRails::Engine => '/swagger'`

`Swagger-rails` generates the swagger_doc.json endpoint and I can see the json file.
But when I am visiting `/swagger` endpoint I am getting an error from Firefox

```
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”).
```

This is on the inline script that is been generated on the swagger file.